# WPF DataGrid CheckBox Select All And Get Selected Rows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Datagrid in WPF. I added a checkbox column as follows:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
       <CheckBox Name="CheckALL"  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedAll, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox Name="chkSelect" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Now property changed event gets fired on check box in rows is clicked, But I also want to get all check boxes checked when header check box is clicked.

When Header check box is clicked, All checkboxes are selected when i write code like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
 <CheckBox Name="chkSelect" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=CheckALL,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But at the same time both functions are to be obtained.
Please help me

Comment: check this answer .. i hope this helpful..http://stackoverflow.com/a/25043588

Comment: @PradnyaBolli: check my edited question. sorry for the delay

Comment: you want to like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28394529

Comment: Here, my datagrid is dynamically binding, so hope its not worthy

Comment: Try this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f100d/checkbox-checked-and-un-checked-events-in-data-grid-header/
and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1609082-e064-4a6b-aa92-93e21ded5fa2/select-all-checkbox-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: well tbh I couldn't understand your question, can you please explain what both functions are we talking about here and what exactly is your question ?

Comment: @Muds:  My requirement is: if i Click checkbox in datagrid header, all check boxes in datagrid is to be selected, else I want to get all rows if any check box in datagrid row, if selected

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<Checkbox Name="CheckALL">
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckColumns}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=hereNameOfGrid}"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Checkbox>
```

now u need a command in your code which  could look like this:

```
public void CheckColumns(object _grid)
{
        GridView tempGrid = _grid as GridView;

        foreach (var item in tempGrid.Columns)
        {
            item.IsChecked = false;
        }    
}
```

Something like that should work. This is not working code, its just a hint to a solution!

Comment: xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"